# Mimic C usage in preexisting R package

Tags: c, r, lapack

I am trying to use C code within R based on the package `QUIC`. Unfortunately I can't get my own local version of the package to work. I downloaded the package source from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/QUIC/index.html) for examination. In the `src` folder I find the desired QUIC.cpp code ([A github page contains it here for reference](https://github.com/tjhunter/navigate-sf/blob/master/python/mm/arterial_hkt/gmrf_learning/quic_cpp/QUIC.C)) and a Makevars file with no extension that contains the following two lines:

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -DLANG_R
```

Next, I run `R CMD SHLIB QUIC.cpp` in Terminal (there are no warnings or errors produced), and then I load into R with `dyn.load(QUIC.so)`. When I try to run the corresponding `QUIC` function in R using my created `.so` file I get an error message:

> Error: BLAS/LAPACK routine 'DPOTRF' gave error code -4

The `dpotrf` call performs a choleksy decomposition and the error is not because of lack of positive definiteness or anything "theoretical" . . . I'm not sure how to fix this and can't find anything helpful online.

EDIT: to be clear, all of this is done in the downloaded `QUIC` package and I have not changed any code. The desired function works perfectly when I perform `library(QUIC)` and use it from there. I want to eventually change their C code since I think the `QUIC` method can be extended, but first I need to get `QUIC` working in this manner!

EDIT2: Here are some system details.

```
> Sys.info()
                                     sysname 
                                     "Darwin" 
                                     release 
                                     "16.7.0" 
                                     version 
"Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0; root:xnu-3789.73.8~1/RELEASE_X86_64" 
                                    nodename 
                                     "MacBook-Pro.local" 
                                     machine 
                                    "x86_64" 

> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "darwin15.6.0"

$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin15.6.0"


$`svn rev`
[1] "74626"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)"

$nickname
[1] "Joy in Playing"
```

EDIT3:  Here is the code I use to test.

```
n <- 15
rho <- 0.2
S <- diag(n)
# library(QUIC); QUIC(S,rho) works fine. Now copying the setup for QUIC and trying with .so file:


path = NULL; tol = 1e-04; msg = 1; maxIter = 1000; X.init = NULL; W.init = NULL

if (is.null(path)) {
        npath <- 1
    } else {npath <- length(path)}
    if (!is.matrix(rho) && length(rho) != 1 && length(rho) != 
        n) {
        stop("Wrong number of elements in rho")
    }
    if (is.vector(rho)) {
        rho <- matrix(sqrt(rho)) %*% sqrt(rho)
    }
    if (length(rho) == 1) {
        rho <- matrix(rho, ncol = n, nrow = n)
    }
    if (is.null(path)) {
        if (is.null(X.init)) {
            X <- diag(n)
            W <- diag(n)
        } else {
            X <- X.init
            W <- W.init }
    } else {
        if (is.null(X.init)) {
            X <- array(diag(n), c(n, n, npath))
            W <- array(diag(n), c(n, n, npath))
        } else {
            X <- array(0, c(n, n, npath))
            W <- array(0, c(n, n, npath))
            X[, , 1] <- X.init
            W[, , 1] <- W.init
        }
    }
    opt <- matrix(0, ncol = npath, nrow = 1)
    cputime <- matrix(0, ncol = npath, nrow = 1)
    iter <- matrix(0, ncol = npath, nrow = 1)
    dGap <- matrix(0, ncol = npath, nrow = 1)
    if (is.null(path)) {
        job <- "d"
    } else {job <- "p"}
    storage.mode(job) <- "character"
    storage.mode(S) <- "double"
    storage.mode(rho) <- "double"
    storage.mode(npath) <- "integer"
    storage.mode(path) <- "double"
    storage.mode(tol) <- "double"
    storage.mode(msg) <- "integer"
    storage.mode(maxIter) <- "integer"
    storage.mode(X) <- "double"
    storage.mode(W) <- "double"
    storage.mode(opt) <- "double"
    storage.mode(cputime) <- "double"
    storage.mode(iter) <- "integer"
    storage.mode(dGap) <- "double"

 dyn.load(".../QUIC.so")    

tmp <- .C("QUICR", job, n, S, rho, npath, path, tol, msg, 
        maxIter, X = X, W = W, opt = opt, cputime = cputime, 
        iter = iter, dGap = dGap)

#Error: BLAS/LAPACK routine 'DPOTRF' gave error code -4
```

Comment: does it work if you instead `R CMD INSTALL QUIC`, then within R `library(QUIC); <whatever>` using the directory unpacked from the downloaded tarball?

Comment: I honestly do not understand your question. _Either_ you just "clone" the existing package, keeping its structure and making a new one _or_ you want to access the C code of the existing package.  The former is easy and has been done millions of time, the latter is possible and I answered it on this site a few times too.

Comment: In either case you already quote the full link instructions with LAPACK, BLAS and Fortran.  You need that too -- you cannot just `dyn.load()` an incompletely linked routine and hope for unicorns and rainbows.  _There is a reason we all insist on building packages_ and you are experiencing one of the reasons why. Packages work, and have a build framework.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes I can download the tarball from CRAN and run "R CMD INSTALL QUIC_1.1.tar.gz" and everything is fine. I will note that if I delete the MD5 from the tarball and try to install it fails. @Dirk Eddelbuettel The package consists of a function QUIC (code in `QUIC.cpp`) which uses this C code via `.C` command in R. When I try the exact same thing but create the QUIC function from a properly loaded `.so` it throws LAPACK error. I thought the LAPACK links are within the QUIC.cpp header and the Makevars file but I am quite clueless overall. I don't care about making a package.

Comment: I know a lot less than @DirkEddelbuettel , but it seems that the path of least resistance would be to develop your extensions by modifying the code and building it *within* the existing package structure (you can edit the `DESCRIPTION` file to change the name, use `devtools::load_all()` to recompile/reload on the fly, etc...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that, in the original `QUIC.r` function, the line:

```
n <- nrow(S)
```

gives `n` a `storage.mode` of `integer`.  However, in your code, you assign:

```
n <- 15
```

which gives `n` a `storage.mode` of `double`.

If you add:

```
storage.mode(n) <- "integer"
```

to the big list of storage mode settings, your program should work fine.